# Appcelerator Force All TableView Rows to Render on Load

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Here's a doozy.  I have a TableView with programmatically added custom TableViewRows.  They are custom in that they have a left-aligned label and a right-aligned switch (think of it as a browse filter).  I inserted the same type of row at the top to programmatically toggle all switches on/off.

All of this works as intended EXCEPT when I have more rows than can fit on the screen and attempt to toggle all.  In this case, the custom row switches off-screen haven't rendered when the view loaded and therefore don't fire their changed event when handled programmatically.

If I manually scroll to the bottom to force render all rows then attempt to toggle all, it works just fine.

Is there a way to force all TableView rows (even those off screen) to render when the view loads?  Or is there a workaround that I can live with?

Comment: Lazy rendering is builtin behaviour in the iOS and Android SDKs to improve performance. I don't believe we can disable that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current workaround.  In the window OnOpen event, I call my function to initialize table data.  This is important because this makes sure the first load works.

Then I force scrollToIndex to the last row then immediately scrollToIndex back to the first row.  Since I do this right after adding rows, I need to do use setTimeout to make sure it covers load time.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.tblOptions.scrollToIndex(lastIndex, { animated: false, position: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewScrollPosition.BOTTOM });
}, 0);
```

Since this creates a jumpy user experience, I hide the table during load, show an activity indicator, then re-show table after load.

This will work for now but I'm still wondering if there is a simpler solution.